# JQuery UI - Draggable is not working when a text is inside of a div-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to drag and resize some div-boxes which is working pretty fine (except that it moves my other boxes when I am resizing a box, maybe someone has also an idea why).

The problem, when I am inserting text by using jQuery inside of the `div` box the box is still draggable but not resizable anymore and I do not know why.

```
function displayRooms() {
  for(i=0; i < room_count; i++) {
    //console.log(i);
    var room_test = "#room" + i;
    //console.log(room_test);
    if($(room_test).length == 0) {
      $(".rooms").append(rooms[i]);
    }
  }
  $(".room").draggable();
  $(".room").resizable();
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a working example that shows your problem?

Comment: What is contained in the `rooms` array?  Need to see a bit more. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve